# HOW to set Focus on a hidden Textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In my `page_load` event I have this code :

```
myTextbox.focus().
```

So when I set my textbox to `visible=false` my code doesn't work.

Comment: hidden:elements can't be focused,clicked,keyup.....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hidden controls are not focusable. Set the Opacity to 0 instead.

Comment: That is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. If something isn't rendered, it cannot be interacted with, so you cannot set the focus to it.

Answer (score 1):

Focus means that user input is focused to the control, that means if the control is a text-box, the text input cursor will be placed in the control or if it is a checkbox, the checkbox will be focused and may be selected by pressing space, you can't put a text input cursor in a hidden control and it cannot be used for any user input.

If you still want to set focus for some reason, try setting its height and width to Zero.
Like `style="height:0px; width:0px"`
and use `Page.SetFocus(yourControl);` to set focus

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `Control.Visible` property to false it doesn't just hide the control on the page.  It omits that control from being rendered on the client's browser entirely, but "remembers" everything about that control on the server for future postbacks.

If you actually do a client side hide (i.e. set the CSS Style `display: none;` then it will still exist on the page, but just be hidden.  At that point you can focus it.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to set visibility:hidden but it doesn't work to