# Focusing on hidden asp.net controls

Tags: asp.net

I tried focusing a control in my `aspx` page but I am not able to focus on any hidden(`visibility='false'`) controls. Why is it so? what is the reason behind such a design?

Comment: Why would you want to focus a hidden control? Hidden controls are not visible to users. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a page where on certain user action I would want the page to scroll to the bottom, where I would be having some hidden control placed

Comment: This question already has an answer. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672520/how-to-set-focus-on-a-hidden-textbox

Comment: @Vaishali please read the details of the question. I am trying to figure out the reson behind such a design

Comment: Usually if you want to scroll to the bottom you would place something visible but empty at the bottom. For example a <div id="myScrollToDiv"></div>. Then you find the div by its id using javascript and scroll to the div. Focus on the other hand means that user *input* is focused to the control, that means that if the control is a textbox, the text input cursor will be placed in the control or if it is a checkbox the checkbox will focused and may be selected by pressing space, you can't put a text input cursor in a hidden control and it cannot be used for any user input.

Comment: Thnx @mortb for the clarification.

Comment: Not a problem :) Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Hidden controls are used to store state values. They are not used to store any security sensitive information. They can be used only to help in developer point of view not in user point of view. So they dont need to have focus. **visibility='false'** hides the control but still occupies the space for the control. **Display='none'** can be used to avoid space constraints. I think, this may help you.